# How to read a File from the local storage (say "C:\\" ) using UWP Backbround Task?

Tags: uwp, electron

Is there any way to read a file from the local drive(say `C:\\eUWP\\UnReleasedFeatureTest.txt` )
I have a background task which has to read some data from a file and the path is `C:\\eUWP`.

Below is my sample code snippet.

```
[DataContract]
public sealed class ConfigFileDetail
{
    [DataMember]
    public string TestingUnreleasedFeatures { get; set; }                
}
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    string filepath = "C:\\eUWP\\UnReleasedFeatureTest.txt";
    string result = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(filepath)) { 
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open)))
            {
                var jsonData = r.ReadToEnd();
                DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ConfigFileDetail));
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData));
                stream.Position = 0;
                ConfigFileDetail dataContractDetail = (ConfigFileDetail)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);
                ShowToast("Hi Praveer, I'm Electron's UWP sidekick" + dataContractDetail.TestingUnreleasedFeatures);
                UpdateTile("Hi Praveer see result, I'm Electron's UWP sidekick");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The error message is " + e.ToString());
    }
}
```

I also tried using `StorageFile` , but unfortunately, it didn't work

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = 
   Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = 
   await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("E:\\eUWP\\UnReleasedFeatureTest.txt");
```

is there any way I can access the file from the local drive from the background Task ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can never access a file on arbitrary path on hard drive using `System.IO` APIs - that is blocked due to safety reasons, so that UWP apps run in a silo and can't break anything on the host PC.

You can however make it work through `StorageFile` API, but you first need to declare the `broadFileSystemAccess` in the `Package.appxmanifest` file. Open it in text editor and update the root element as follows:

```
<Package
  ...
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
```

In the `<Capabilities>` element you can now declare:

```
<rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
```

Now your second suggested solution with `StorageFile` should be able to access the file as long as the user didn't disable filesystem access in the settings.

For more detailed information [check out the Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations).

Comment: Thanks for your response.
 I updated `Package.appxmanifest` file. 
Now, I am using the `StorageFile` and below is my code. 

    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = 
       Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    
    
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = 
       await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("E:\\eUWP\\UnReleasedFeatureTest.txt");

Error:

 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007B)'

Comment: It expects the file in
`C:\Users\kumarpr\AppData\Local\Packages\8d0bb065-b69f-4da1-ba4c-fcd21d312da0_vp9fjm7zssgd8\LocalState\` directory. However,I want to read from `C:\\eUWP\\` Directory. Is there anyway that I can achieve this.

Comment: Does the file in E:\eUWP\ really exist? If you declare the `broadFilesystemAccess` capability it should work as long as you have permission to access the file as a user

Comment: Oh I see the problem! Don't use `LocalFolder` - that is the `LocalState` directrory. Instead, use the `GetFileFromPathAsync` method directly - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_GetFileFromPathAsync_System_String_

Comment: @ Martin Zikmund : Thanks for your response. But,Unfortunately, `GetFileFromPathAsync()` API  also did not help me.

`StorageFile filepath = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync("E:\eUWP\UnReleasedFeatureTest.txt");`

It keeps waiting to get the response from the API. Actually in my case it hanged at the above code .

Comment: Maybe it is a problem of the backward slash \ needs to be written as \\ in the path (so that it does not do string escape instead)

Comment: Otherwise this is very weird... It definitely should not hang in particular, but throw instead an exception at least...

Comment: I tried by using `\\' even though  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_GetFileFromPathAsync_System_String_

tutorial didnt mention about it. but It really didn not work. Its very hard to understand why its not working. I need to try again and see if I can access a file from `E:\eUWP\UnReleasedFeatureTest.txt`

Comment: Just to verify, can you try some other arbitrary file, something like on your desktop or so?

Comment: Let me create a repository in github and share with you, if in case you get  time , please have a look on it.might be I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I see a flaw in the code you showed.

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder; 
Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("E:\\eUWP\\UnReleasedFeatureTest.txt");
```

Your StorageFolder is from the current LocalFolder. Set this to the folder where the file is. In this example, that looks like E:\eUWP

Comment: No We can not do that, It seems to me that we do not get access to the `arbitrary path` I have asked many people about it but didnt get any feedback yet

Comment: I'm sorry. You will continue to experience these errors if you try to access files that aren't in the specified folder.

Comment: I didn’t understand what you meant to say.could you show me the sample code. I tried all the way but it didn’t work

Comment: Here is the detail chat I did with one of the expert

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198286/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-praveer-kumar

Comment: If you have the text file in the folder "E:\eUWP\" what happens when you run the same code, but specifying the storage folder as E:\eUWP? 
Is this still hanging? How long does it hang for? 
Or is there an exception? what are the full exception details? Exception object's ToString method will print full details for an exception. Please be sure to also include any InnerException or InnerExceptions.
Does the same code work if it's not in a background task? Say, if it's in a button's click handler?
Can you share an updated, minimized sample of your project that will reproduce the issue (MCVE)?

Comment: If the code change I suggested here, to update the folder path, doesn't resolve the issue, then it sounds like file system access hasn't been manually enabled by user. I added a new solution (not comment) that accounts for this and includes the code I used.

Answer (score 0):

This didn't repro for me.

I created a background task with an app trigger, triggered it, and read the file okay. The code I used follows.

After testing, feel free to arrange the code as needed. This is just one way. Also note, this is proof of concept and not production ready code as that's a much broader topic. The purpose here is to demonstrate file access from background.

As you mentioned, you'll need broadfilesystemaccess capability outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations. Additionally, you'll need user to manually allow file system access. You'll want to check from your main app in the foreground if you have access and prompt the user to enable the setting if it's not already enabled. This is discussed in the 'Accessing Additional locations" section of this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations, under the broadFileSystemAccess capability description.

From App.xaml.cs

```
// NOTE: docs are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task
protected override async void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnBackgroundActivated(args);
    IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance = args.TaskInstance;
    await ReadText(taskInstance);
}

// NOTE: docs are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage 
// NOTE: sample is here https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FileAccess
public static async Task ReadText(IBackgroundTaskInstance backgroundTaskInstance = null)
{
    // TODO: update the paths; these are the paths on my machine.
    string folderName = "D:\\out";
    string fileName = "helloworld.txt";
    var storageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(folderName);
    var storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);

    var E_NO_UNICODE_TRANSLATION = unchecked((int)0x80070459); 
    if (storageFile != null)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileContents = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile);
            Debug.WriteLine($"The following text was read from '{storageFile.Name}':{Environment.NewLine}{fileContents}");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (ex.HResult == E_NO_UNICODE_TRANSLATION)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Could not decode file to Unicode.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // I/O errors are reported as exceptions.
            Debug.WriteLine($"Error reading from '{storageFile.Name}':{Environment.NewLine}{ex.ToString()}");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("File wasn't found");
    }
}
```

From MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    await TriggerBackgroundTask();
}

// NOTE: docs are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/trigger-background-task-from-app
ApplicationTrigger _AppTrigger;
private async Task TriggerBackgroundTask()
{
    _AppTrigger = new ApplicationTrigger();

    var requestStatus = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
    if (requestStatus != BackgroundAccessStatus.AlwaysAllowed)
    {
        string taskName = "Example application trigger";
        BackgroundTaskRegistration task = RegisterBackgroundTask(taskName, _AppTrigger);
        var result = await _AppTrigger.RequestAsync();
    }
}

// NOTE: docs are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task
public static BackgroundTaskRegistration RegisterBackgroundTask(string taskName,
                                                                IBackgroundTrigger trigger,
                                                                string taskEntryPoint = null,
                                                                IBackgroundCondition condition = null)
{
    // Check for existing registrations of this background task.
    foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
    {

        if (cur.Value.Name == taskName)
        {
            // The task is already registered.
            return (BackgroundTaskRegistration)(cur.Value);
        }
    }

    // Register the background task.
    var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
    builder.Name = taskName;
    builder.SetTrigger(trigger);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(taskEntryPoint))
    {
        builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
    }

    if (condition != null)
    {

        builder.AddCondition(condition);
    }

    BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
    return task;
}
```

If this doesn't resolve the issue for you, please share a minimized sample to reproduce the issue (MCVE).

Comment: I get 
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

I have a repository in git hub
https://github.com/Praveer1981/ElectronBacgroundTaskApp